# IMAP не работает SMTP работает

Tags: debian, smtp, postfix, imap, dovecot

Есть почтовый сервер (Postfix + Dovecot). Сертификат самоподписанный. Почтовые клиенты не могут получить письма с сервера (подключаюсь из Thunderbird STARTSSL :143), при этом отправка писем без защиты работает как положено, а при включении STARTSSL письма не отправляются с ошибкой "Не удалось установить соединение с сервером).

В логах `mail.log` и `mail.err` ничего особенного нет.

master.cf

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = domainName.ru
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

# TLS parameters
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/certificate/smtpd.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/certificate/smtpd.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_loglevel = 3
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/domainName.ru2016-bundle;
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/www.domainName.ru.key;
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /root/mailCert/mail.domainName.ru.public.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /root/mailCert/mail.domainName.ru.private.pem
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1,!SSLv3

# MySQL конфигурация
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
# SASL конфигурация
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 reject_unauth_destination,
 reject_unauth_pipelining,
 reject_invalid_hostname,

proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $
virtual_transport = dovecot

milter_protocol = 2
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
```

Comment: Хм. А без сертификата все ОК? Вы часом сертификат не реджектнули в клиентах на совсем?  Кстати, говоря - хорошая идея воспользоваться бесплатным сертификатом. Типа StartSSL или Lets Encrypt.
Порт для защищенного соединения открыт? Попробуйте тем же nmap'ом или telnet'ом подцепиться. Может файрволл тупо рубит соединение (на стороне сервера). И посмотрите отладку в клиенте.

Comment: што сообщает `nestat -ant | grep 143`

Comment: Закомментировал все про SSL, сделал reload. Перенастроил клиент на 143 и 25 порты, отправка работает, получение - нет. По telnet отвечает только 25 порт. Остальные или Refused, либо Software connection abort

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip `netstat -ant | grep 143` - `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: 143-й порт в вашем случае должен слушать процесс *dovecot*, а не *postfix* (это совершенно разные программы). задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос по этому поводу.

Comment: Подозреваю что 143 слушает dovecot. Поправьте если ошибаюсь
 `netstat -tulpn | grep :143
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16750/dovecot`